# jQuery: How can I edit this code to produce a fade effect instead of a sliding effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade, slide

I'm having trouble making the following code fade an image instead of sliding an image. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
var rotate_delay = 7000;

(function($) {
$.fn.preload = function(options) {
    var opts    = $.extend({}, $.fn.preload.defaults, options);
    o           = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, this.data()) : opts;
    var c       = this.length,
        l       = 0;
    return this.each(function() {
        var $i  = $(this);
        $('<img/>').load(function(i){
            ++l;
            if(l == c) o.onComplete();
        }).attr('src',$i.attr('src'));  
    });
};
$.fn.preload.defaults = {
    onComplete  : function(){return false;}
};
})(jQuery);


$(function() {
var $tf_bg              = $('#tf_bg'),
    $tf_bg_images       = $tf_bg.find('img'),
    $tf_bg_img          = $tf_bg_images.eq(0),
    $tf_thumbs          = $('#tf_thumbs'),
    total               = $tf_bg_images.length,
    current             = 0,
    $tf_content_wrapper = $('#tf_content_wrapper'),
    $tf_next            = $('#tf_next'),
    $tf_prev            = $('#tf_prev'),
    $tf_loading         = $('#tf_loading');

//preload the images                
$tf_bg_images.preload({
    onComplete  : function(){
        $tf_loading.hide();
        init();
    }
});




//shows the first image and initializes events
function init(){
    //get dimentions for the image, based on the windows size
    var dim = getImageDim($tf_bg_img);
    //set the returned values and show the image
    $tf_bg_img.css({
        width   : dim.width,
        height  : dim.height,
        left    : dim.left,
        top     : dim.top
    }).fadeIn();

    //resizing the window resizes the $tf_bg_img
$(window).bind('resize',function(){
    var dim = getImageDim($tf_bg_img);
    $tf_bg_img.css({
        width   : dim.width,
        height  : dim.height,
        left    : dim.left,
        top     : dim.top
    });
});

    //expand and fit the image to the screen
    $('#tf_zoom').live('click',
        function(){
        if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
            return false;

            var $this   = $(this);
            if($this.hasClass('tf_zoom')){
                resize($tf_bg_img);
                $this.addClass('tf_fullscreen')
                     .removeClass('tf_zoom');
            }
            else{
                var dim = getImageDim($tf_bg_img);
                $tf_bg_img.animate({
                    width   : dim.width,
                    height  : dim.height,
                    top     : dim.top,
                    left    : dim.left
                },350);
                $this.addClass('tf_zoom')
                     .removeClass('tf_fullscreen'); 
            }
        }
    );

    var rotate_timeout;

    //click the arrow down, scrolls down
    $tf_next.bind('click',function(){
        if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
            return false;
            clearInterval(rotate_timeout);
            scroll('tb');
    });

    //click the arrow up, scrolls up
    $tf_prev.bind('click',function(){
        if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
        return false;
        clearInterval(rotate_timeout);
        scroll('bt');
    });

    function rotate()
    {   
        if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
        return false;
        scroll('tb');
    }

    rotate_timeout = setInterval(rotate, rotate_delay);

    //mousewheel events - down / up button trigger the scroll down / up
    $(document).mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
        if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
            return false;

        if(delta > 0)
            scroll('bt');
        else
            scroll('tb');
        return false;
    });

    //key events - down / up button trigger the scroll down / up
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
            return false;

        switch(e.which){
            case 38:    
                scroll('bt');
                break;  

            case 40:    
                scroll('tb');
                break;
        }
    });
}

//show next / prev image
function scroll(dir){
    //if dir is "tb" (top -> bottom) increment current, 
    //else if "bt" decrement it
    current = (dir == 'tb')?current + 1:current - 1;

    //we want a circular slideshow, 
    //so we need to check the limits of current
    if(current == total) current = 0;
    else if(current < 0) current = total - 1;

    //flip the thumb
    $tf_thumbs.flip({
        direction   : dir,
        speed       : 400,
        onBefore    : function(){
            //the new thumb is set here
            var content = '<span id="tf_zoom" class="tf_zoom">       </span>';
            content     +='<img src="' +      $tf_bg_images.eq(current).attr('longdesc') + '" alt="Thumb' + (current+1) + '"/>';
            $tf_thumbs.html(content);
    }
    });

    //we get the next image
    var $tf_bg_img_next = $tf_bg_images.eq(current),
        //its dimentions
        dim             = getImageDim($tf_bg_img_next),
        //the top should be one that makes the image out of the viewport
        //the image should be positioned up or down depending on the direction
            top = (dir == 'tb')?$(window).height() + 'px':-parseFloat(dim.height,10) + 'px';

    //set the returned values and show the next image   
        $tf_bg_img_next.css({
            width   : dim.width,
            height  : dim.height,
            left    : dim.left,
            top     : top
        }).show();

    //now slide it to the viewport
        $tf_bg_img_next.stop().animate({
            top     : dim.top
        },1000);

    //we want the old image to slide in the same direction, out of the viewport
        var slideTo = (dir == 'tb')?-$tf_bg_img.height() + 'px':$(window).height() + 'px';
        $tf_bg_img.stop().animate({
            top     : slideTo
        },1000,function(){
        //hide it
            $(this).hide();
        //the $tf_bg_img is now the shown image
            $tf_bg_img  = $tf_bg_img_next;
        //show the description for the new image

        var desc = $tf_content_wrapper.children().eq(current);
        jQuery("h2, p",desc).css("opacity", 0);
        var speed = 1000, titlesFactor = 0, titlespeed = 1000, titleeasing = 'swing';

        desc.show()
                  .find('h2')
                  .css('left', -50 + 'px' )
                  .stop()
                  .delay( speed * titlesFactor )
                  .animate({ left : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, titlespeed, titleeasing)
                  .end()
                  .find('p')
                  .css( 'left', 50 + 'px' )
                  .stop()
                  .delay( speed * titlesFactor )
                  .animate({ left : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, titlespeed, titleeasing)
                  .end();

});
    //hide the current description  
        $tf_content_wrapper.children(':visible')
                           .hide()

}

//animate the image to fit in the viewport
function resize($img){
    var w_w = $(window).width(),
        w_h = $(window).height(),
        i_w = $img.width(),
        i_h = $img.height(),
        r_i = i_h / i_w,
        new_w,new_h;

    if(i_w > i_h){
        new_w   = w_w;
        new_h   = w_w * r_i;

        if(new_h > w_h){
            new_h   = w_h;
            new_w   = w_h / r_i;
        }
    }   
    else{
        new_h   = w_w * r_i;
        new_w   = w_w;
    }

    $img.animate({
        width   : new_w + 'px',
        height  : new_h + 'px',
        top     : '0px',
        left    : '0px'
    },350);
}

//get dimentions of the image, 
//in order to make it full size and centered
function getImageDim($img){
    var w_w = $(window).width(),
        w_h = $(window).height(),
        r_w = w_h / w_w,
        i_w = $img.width(),
        i_h = $img.height(),
        r_i = i_h / i_w,
        new_w,new_h,
        new_left,new_top;

    if(r_w > r_i){
        new_h   = w_h;
        new_w   = w_h / r_i;
    }
    else{
        new_h   = w_w * r_i;
        new_w   = w_w;
    }


    return {
        width   : new_w + 'px',
        height  : new_h + 'px',
        left    : (w_w - new_w) / 2 + 'px',
        top     : (w_h - new_h) / 2 + 'px'
    };
    }
});
```

This isn't my code, I'm trying to make edits so that it will achieve the effect that I am after, i.e. fade

Thanks again.

Comment: here's a site showing the slide animation [http://nico.nicolette.ro/](http://nico.nicolette.ro/)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `show()` with `fadeIn(timeout)` and the `hide()` with `fadeOut(timeout)`.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for replying. Do I change all the 'show()' and 'hide()' to the ones stated by yourself? Excuse my ignorance, this is the first time I'm trying to do this :)

Comment: Yeah and put the necessary timeout in milliseconds.